# Use DataBinding on Combo

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, converters

I try to use [DataBinding](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) on SWT Widgets.

I´m wondering if there is a way to connect a [Combo Box](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html) to an underlying [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in the model. 
So I have a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in the Model and a [Combo](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html) on my View?

As the standard way is not working:

```
//View
DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();
IObservableValue target1 = WidgetProperties.singleSelectionIndex().observe(combo);
IObservableValue model1 = BeanProperties.value(OutputVariable.class, "type").observe(outputVariable);
ctx.bindValue(target1, model1);

//Model
public void setType(String type) {
    //TYPES is a constant with the possible Combo values
    if (contains(TYPES, type)) {
        String oldType = this.type;
        this.type = type;
        firePropertyChange("type", oldType, this.type);
    }else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

I tried to use the [fireIndexedPropertyChangeMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html#fireIndexedPropertyChange%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) which didn't worked either.

Is there a way to connect those two together? Maybe I have to use another [WidgetProperties](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fswt%2FWidgetProperties.html) or [BeanProperties](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fdatabinding%2Fbeans%2FBeanProperties.html) method?

As a workaround I could maybe use a new Property in the model, which defines the combo selection index, connect this to the [Combo](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html) and transfer changes of this index to the type Property and vice versa. But that seems not as a great solution to me.

Edit: 
The Solution with a selectionIndex Property is working. But a cleaner method would still be nice as now a type Property change in the model has to reset the selectionIndex too and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a clean solution now, which is to use a Converter.

```
//View
    IObservableValue comboObservable = WidgetProperties.singleSelectionIndex().observe(combo);
    IObservableValue viewTypeObservable = BeanProperties.value(DebugModel.class, "type").observe(debugModel);

    IConverter viewTypeToIntConverter = createViewTypeToIntConverter();
    UpdateValueStrategy toTargetStrategy = new UpdateValueStrategy();
    toTargetStrategy.setConverter(viewTypeToIntConverter);

    IConverter intToViewTypeConverter = createIntToViewTypeConverter();
    UpdateValueStrategy toModelStrategy = new UpdateValueStrategy();
    toModelStrategy.setConverter(intToViewTypeConverter);

    DataBindingContext context = new DataBindingContext();
    context.bindValue(comboObservable, viewTypeObservable, toModelStrategy, toTargetStrategy);

//Converter
private IConverter createIntToViewTypeConverter() {
    return new IConverter() {

        @Override
        public Object convert(Object value) {
            if(value instanceof Integer) {
                for(ViewType type : ViewType.values()) {
                    if(type.toString().equals(ViewType.getStringAtIndex((int)value))) {
                        return type;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("We need an Integer to convert it but got an " + value.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public Object getFromType() {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getToType() {
            return ViewType.class;
        }

    };
}

private IConverter createViewTypeToIntConverter() {
    return new IConverter() {

        @Override
        public Object convert(Object value) {
            if(value instanceof ViewType) {
                String[] viewTypes = ViewType.getStringValues();
                for(int i=0;i<viewTypes.length;i++) {
                    if(viewTypes[i].equals(((ViewType)value).toString())) {
                        return i;
                    }
                } 
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("We need a View Type to be converted but got a " + value.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public Object getFromType() {
            return ViewType.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getToType() {
            return Integer.class;
        }

    };
}

//Model
public class DebugModel extends ModelObject {
    private ViewType type;
    public ViewType getType() {
         return type;
    }

    public void setType(ViewType type) {
        firePropertyChange("type", this.type, this.type = type);
    }
}

//Just to complete the example, be sure the Model class extends a ModelObject class like this
public class ModelObject {
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(
        this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
        PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
        PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue,
        Object newValue) {
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    protected void fireIndexedPropertyChange(String propertyName, int index, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        changeSupport.fireIndexedPropertyChange(propertyName, index, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

Of course you can outsource the Converters to custom classes, I used it this way just to show a quick solution here.